NavigationSplitView .searchable giving "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute"
I'm getting "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute" when using the searchSuggestions modifier for NavigationSplitView. This is for Mac platform
struct ContentView: View {

    let platforms: [String] = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"]
    
    @State var selection: String = ""
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(platforms, id: \.self) { platform in
                    if platform.contains(searchText) || searchText.isEmpty {
                        Text(platform).tag(platform)
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            switch(selection) {
            default:
                if selection.isEmpty {
                    Text("Make a selection")
                } else {
                    Text(selection)
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .sidebar)
        .searchSuggestions({
            Text("test").searchCompletion("test123")
        })
    }
}

If you remove .searchSuggestions then everything works as expected. However with that modifier, the console outputs AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute
A theory I have - I set a symbolic breakpoint for AG: print_cycles() and see that the NSWindow takes the first responder, so maybe the suggestions popover and NSWindow fight for responder and causes the cycle?

Could not reproduce your issue/warning/error. On MacOS 15.1, using Xcode 16.1,
tested on MacOS 15.1.

Thanks for checking, I'm MacOS 14.7 Xcode 16.0. Will update my system and check

I can repro it on MacOS 15.0.1 and Xcode 16.1, can you try searching for something and clicking on the popover?

tried again, however I don't get any "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute" in the console.
